# Pass value and text from SELECT/OPTION to another SELECT/OPTION jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clone a option when selected and pass it into another form.

What am I trying to do?
I am building a mailscript where you can choose your receivers by handling 2-3 forms by adding or deleting options in a form.

Form1 already got values.

Form2 needs a value from form1, and here is the problem.

How can I do this the best way?

This is what I got so far:

```
$('.valj_grupp_email').change(function() {
    $('.add_button').click(function(){
        $('.valj_grupp_email').find(":selected").text().insertAfter('.valda_grupper_email');
    });
});
```

Comment: not clear what actual behavior you want. Move selected `<option>`'s to other form? copy them to form? Keep them selected? A more detailed explnation would help along with some html. Also clcik handler inside change handler diesn't seem right...can end up with new clcik handler for everry change. 10 changes = 10 clcik handlers firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<select id="sel1" multiple size="4">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2" multiple size="4">
    <option value="dummy">Dummy</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" id="doBtn" value="do it">
```

JS

```
$('#doBtn').click(function () {
    $('#sel1 option:selected').each(function () {
        $("<option/>").
        val($(this).val()).
        text($(this).text()).
        appendTo("#sel2");
    });
});
```

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wnNfc

Comment: Thank you fr4nk, I really appreciate it!

And if I want to delete from "#sel2" I just do the same thing but use .remove instead of appendTo?

Comment: i think you can just use `$(this).remove();` in the each-loop!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Just figured it out my self and was about to post it. Thank you for your help!